# How to resolve "404 not found" error in ASP.NET MVC project when getting a JsonResult?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a cascading drop-down in an ASP.NET project.
Here is my code for view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, ViewBag.States as SelectList, "All", new { @class = "from-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RegionId, ViewBag.Regions as SelectList, "All", new { @class = "from-control" })

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StateId").change(function () {
            $.get("/User/GetRegions", { StateId: $("#StateId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#RegionId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#RegionId").append("<option value='" + row.RegionId + "'>" + row.Title + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

And here the controller code

```cs
public JsonResult GetRegions(int StateId)
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    List<Region> Regions = db.Regions.Where(r => r.StateId == StateId).ToList();
    return Json(Regions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now when I select an option form state drop-down it shows an "404 Not Found Error" in the console.

Comment: Your error occurs before the json part, so that's not really relevant.   The path `/User/GetRegions` doesn't match with your `[unspecified_controller_name]/GetRegions`.   Is GetRegions in UserController?  Or some other controller?   Is your `<script>` in your Razor file (I'm guessing yes) or is a .js file?   Can try try `$.get("@Url.Action("GetRegions", "User")", ...`   (I think this exact syntax may change depending on the version of MVC, so may not work for you).

Comment: Controller is "UserController" and the script is in Razor file.

Comment: @freedomn-m it says "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"

Comment: My apologizes the controller name is "CustomerController" not the "UserController" for action results I was using routes with "User/---" and it was working but for the JsonResult it didn't and worked after change the controller name.

Comment: So the solution is to change `/User/GetRegions` to `/Customer/GetRegions`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes